# How to declare variable in trigger in MySQL ? As I am getting error while executing few lines for the code

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I want to execute the following code in MySql but I am getting the error

```
CREATE TRIGGER CINEMAHALLNO_GENERATE_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON CINEMA_HALLS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE cnt DOUBLE;
  DECLARE next1 DOUBLE;
  SELECT COUNT(HALLNO) INTO cnt from CINEMA_HALLS;
  IF cnt > 0 AND cnt < 20 THEN
    SELECT MAX(HALLNO) INTO NEXT1 FROM CINEMA_HALLS;
    set next1=next1+1;
    SET :new.HALLNO=next;
  ELSEIF cnt = 0 THEN
    SET :new.HALLNO=1;
  end if;
  end;
```

Output Error:
SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER CINEMAHALLNO_GENERATE_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON CINEMA_HALLS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE cnt DOUBLE
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: NEW. values should not be preceded by :

Answer (score 1):

Declare must be placed after the Begin.
Please check the following [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php)

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER CINEMAHALLNO_GENERATE_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON CINEMA_HALLS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE cnt DOUBLE;
  DECLARE next1 DOUBLE;
  SELECT COUNT(HALLNO) INTO cnt from CINEMA_HALLS;
  IF cnt > 0 AND cnt < 20 THEN
    SELECT MAX(HALLNO) INTO NEXT1 FROM CINEMA_HALLS;
    set next1=next1+1;
    SET :new.HALLNO=next;
  ELSEIF cnt = 0 THEN
    SET :new.HALLNO=1;
  end if;
  end;