# Mariadb before trigger is not updating certain columns

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using mariadb and I have an invoices table. Each invoice has an unique order_number since this is required by law. I have created a before insert trigger like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER `set_invoice_ordernumber` BEFORE INSERT ON invoices FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.year_order_nr = (SELECT MAX(`year_order_nr`) + 1 FROM `invoices` WHERE `company_id`=NEW.company_id AND `year`=NEW.year AND `order_number` IS NOT NULL);
  SET NEW.order_number = CONCAT(NEW.year, '-', LPAD(NEW.year_order_nr, 8, 0));
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

When I do an insert command of an invoice these fields aren't updated. If I add a new column lets say e1 and then add a line SET e1=123; then it does get updated which means that the trigger is executed. What is going on here????

No error is thrown, the fields are just completely ignored.

Comment: do you need to DEFINE the variables before use?

Comment: What variables do you mean? SET NEW.year_order_nr is the field in the row to update. I dont see declare in the examples when using SET NEW.fieldname = ''

Comment: Was looking for similar questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036699/how-to-declare-variable-in-trigger-in-mysql-as-i-am-getting-error-while-execut) and found this from [TechNet](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php)

Comment: As you can see in the example SET NEW.created_date is not declared. So anything with NEW doesnt need declared

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there was another trigger on the table added long ago causing the columns to be set to null. So if something like this happens, make sure there isn't another trigger getting in the way. In phpmyadmin no triggers are displayed so be warned.